# Concavity and inflection points of the function $y= 3x^4 - 10x^3 - 12x - 7$

Tags: calculus

First what I did was take the second derivative of the function and I got $y''= 36x^2-60x$, then set this equal to 0 to solve for $x$. That $x= 0$ and $x=5/3$.

I then tested it's concavity based on the interval I got:

$(-\infty, 0)\to$ Upward

$(0,5/3)\to$ Downward

$(5/3, \infty)\to$ Upward

Is that correct? Why does it concave downwards on the interval $(0, 5/3)$ when in the graph it always concave upwards?

My Inflection points are: $(0,-7)$ and $(5/3, -1354/27)$

Does a parabola have 2 inflection points? What exactly is an inflection point?

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You did it correctly. It might be difficult to see on the graph, try different window settings to see the concave down part clearly.

Comment: It's correct, but it's not always concave upwards everywhere since you just proved that it's concave downwards on $\left(0,\frac{5}{3}\right)$.

Comment: This polynomial is a quartic, so it is not a parabola.  An inflection point is a point where the concavity changes.